# generating a sparse matrix for a categorical variable

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
  x y
1 a d
2 b e
3 c f
```

here x and y are categorical variables. I want to generate a sparse matrix with  one hot encoding for each of the categorical features namely x and y.

I did the following,

```
sparse.model.matrix(~.-1,z)
3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  xa xb xc ye yf
1  1  .  .  .  .
2  .  1  .  1  .
3  .  .  1  .  1
```

I am facing two problems here namely,

1) I need zeros instead of dots and

2) The level d of predictor y is not showing up in the matrix i.e (yd) is not present!!

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: ' zeros instead of dots'? Are you sure you want a sparse matrix. Once you replace missing values with zeros (e.g by `m=as.matrix (m)`), it is no longer sparse.

Comment: mathkid, the dots are interpreted as zeros. eg `mat <- Matrix::Diagonal(2) ; mat[1,2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to specify the `contrasts.arg`

```
as.matrix(sparse.model.matrix(~.-1, z, contrasts.arg = lapply(z,
          function(x) contrasts(factor(x), contrasts = FALSE))))
```

Comment: it seems a bit redundant to use `as.matrix(sparse.model.matrix(`, maybe just `model.matrix`

Answer (score 0):

An option with the caret package:

```
library(caret)

predict(dummyVars(~ ., z), z)    # use sep = '' if you prefer
##   x.a x.b x.c y.d y.e y.f
## 1   1   0   0   1   0   0
## 2   0   1   0   0   1   0
## 3   0   0   1   0   0   1
```